# mongodb atlas search index is not working upon creation of a document using update/upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am facing this weird issue and I was wondering if this was intended.

I have 2 schemas.
BasePost which includes most common attributes for this type of document.(e.g. title, content…)
MarketPost which is a discriminator of “BasePost” which includes extra attributes.

I have search index setup with title and content.

I have post creation code with “UpdateOne” using MarketPost schema with “upsert” option.

Once I create “MarketPost” this post is not searchable until I query this post at least once. Once I query this “MarketPost”, then “MarketPost” is searchable. Let me give more verbose scenario.

1.MarketPost with title: “PS4” is created (using web scrapper, so no actual user interaction)

2.User search with term “PS4” but above MarketPost is not searched.

3.User clicks on this “MarketPost”

4.User search with term “PS4”, now this MarketPost is searched.
My theory is

Upon creating a document with “update and upsert”, document is not properly indexed.

I wonder if my theory is correct, hopefully someone here is able to answer my question.

Thank you.

Comment: While you've given some high level overview in your description, the specific details are going to matter a lot. You mention BasePost once but then never again, how is that schema used later on (eg when searching)? Which collection(s) is your Atlas Search index and query running on? What does your code do when a user clicks on a MarketPost? How long do the different components take (eg time between scraping the entry, the first search, clicking on the item, and the second search)? I don't think there's too much for us to say at this point without more info

Comment: thank you for your input. yes BasePost is used when: 
1. To access generic query on Post (such as FindById or Search) where as MarketPost is simply a discriminator based on BasePost.
2. When MarketPost is accessed, I realized it does "update" query while doing "get" because it needs to update viewcount. I will update all these info!